# jQuery draggable , how to move the draggable object to correct position even though I pan or zoom my image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery.panzoom

I would like to do something like a google map , when someone drag the coordinates inside the google map, no matter the user zoom in or out the coordinates that the user drag will stay at same position , when I try to do this , after I drag my coordinates, and I zoom or pan the image , the coordinates doesn't move to the location where it supposed to be.

Is there any jquery or javascript can achieved that ??

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jokermsi/srpbd4hj/11/)

Thanks in advance for any advice ~~

```
$( function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
} );
```

Comment: google maps recalculates coordinates based on the zoom level (resolution of the "view") that is the way to hold the coordinate at the same place, why don't you try to use google maps api or try openlayers.org

Comment: not that I don't want to use google API , this is a internal project where the PC dont have any internet connection , so I have to do it without internet...